# обновление значений объектов вложенных массивов в mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Есть документ

```
{
    id: 10,
    orders: [
        {
            id: 1
            name: order1,
            files: [
                {id: 1, name: file1}
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2
            name: order2,
            files: [
                {id: 1, name: file1},
                {id: 2, name: file2}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Нужно изменить значение "name" в файле id: 1, заявки id: 2.
Изменить нужно только значение name не перезаписывая объект файла или заявки, или тем более всего документа. Ведь если другой пользователь сделает в документе или order id: 2 изменения, то моё обновление их перезатрёт.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: укажите конкретный путь, который надо обновить

Comment: orders[1].files[0].name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.collection.updateOne({id:10}, {$set:{'orders.1.files.0.name': 'qwerty'}})`